# Everything undefined after postback after removing AjaxControlToolkit ScriptManager

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I just removed AjaxControlToolkit v7 from my project, and therefore replaced the ToolkitScriptManager with the standard ScriptManager.

Now after postback on iframe in popup window all script functions (including jquery, $ etc) are undefined. Just about everything on the window object is undefined. The location is correct and all the script files are there in the head. I put a breakpoint in the script file and when it tries to call a function defined in that very same script file it is undefined.

Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Always ask: "What has changed?"

In my case, I no longer use the Modal Popup Extender with a PERMANENT div. I now use jquery dialog with a dynamic div that I destroy when we click an OK button.

It seems IE still tries to execute scripts after the IFRAME container has been removed from the DOM (with $(div).dialog("destroy").remove()). Chrome at least seems to behave differently and not try to run the scripts.

Related:

[Issue with Iframe inside JQuery dialog only for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263265/issue-with-iframe-inside-jquery-dialog-only-for-ie)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929(v=VS.85).aspx?ppud=4